# I have tested my AWS server (8 GB RAM) on which my Moodle site is hosted for 1000 users using JMeter, I am getting 0% error, what could be the issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, performance-testing, moodle

My moodle site is hosted on AWS Server of 8 GB RAM,  i carried out various tests on the server using JMeter (NFT), I have tested from 15 to almost 1000 users, however I am still not getting any error(less than 0.3%).  I am using the scripts provided by moodle itself. What could be the issue? Is there any issue with the script? I have attached a screenshot with this which shows the reports of 1000 users test for reference[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPmj7.png)

Comment: You want *more* errors?

Comment: I was wondering why the errors are not occurring as the specifications of the machine are not strong enough to handle this type of load

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy with the amount of errors and response times (maximum response time is more than 1 hour which is kind of too much for me) you can stop here and report the results.

However I doubt that a real user will be happy to wait 1 hour to see the login page so I would rather define some realistic pass/fail criteria, for example would expect the response time to be not more than 5 seconds. In this case you will have > 60% of failures if this is what you're trying to achieve.

You can consider using the following test elements

1. Set reasonable response timeouts using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults/):

   [image]

   so if any request will last longer than 5 seconds it will be terminated as failed
2. Or use [Duration Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion)

   [image]

   in this case JMeter will wait for the response and mark it as failed if the response time exceeds the defined duration